# Healthvault Java API:Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty, healthvault

I am trying to test Healthvault Java API with Maven and Jetty.

I am trying examples ui-sdk and ui-jaxb

i can login to the HV but once i login and revert back to my local server my local server display following error

```
WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.microsoft.hsg.applications.weight.AuthenticationPage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters)
and argument target = "[AppAuthSuccess]" wctoken = "[ASAAAAc0l5GS909AhtAG6llej2Ue+qDSLBETgLGSAuLKoLK+9lWhHNNH4w4W0/5jr78FH1ooBhTT4q8CAC/Ukjl6fO52Kq/ksk0t8RdN5WZQZNZW99THGoJLZntv7TRB6hY774q2hsj5yehy6FYERKDYVaUGpc3R5r+hb7seX8AvmildfDeB4iP4EOu3aEug5JTuWg==]" 
actionqs = "[/]"Root cause:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)     at  
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)     at 
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)     at 
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
```

Any one help me is this because of Proxy or Certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because connection is made to host and port, which is not actually listening.

Comment: what is the solution! i tried to set proxy but its not working

Comment: what you are actually trying to do? where is the server running? who is creating the socket? Are the connection properties properly set?